# SortedMap with multiple fields for keys and values

Tags: java

I need to have a sortedMap with these fields for each key
[srcAddr, dstAddr, srcPort, dstPort, protocol] (this is corresponding to a flow)

then this key contains a list of values each containing some fields. such as:
packetLenghth,timeArrival for packet 1
packetLength, timeArrival for packet 2
.
.
.
and so on.

In other words each packet is examined whether it belongs to a Flow or not based on those 5 mentioned fields.
then for that particular packet some informarion will be extracted.
for the next packet, if it belongs to that Flow, a new flow wont be added but information about that packet will be added.

i was thinking of having to separate classes myKeys and myValues each with desired fields.
myKeys need to implement compareTo, hashCode, equal.

but i dont know if im right. can anyone help me with it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution will work.  Having Separate classes for your keys and values will allow you to use a sorted map that maps one to the other as long as the key class implements Comparable which it sounds like is your plan.

Comment: ... and it's always a good habit to implement equals and hashCode (both, not just one) for classes, since one will run into strange bugs later on. Usually one will need to store the objects in a collection, at least when the software grows.

Comment: can you tell me whether i need treeMap for that or not?

Comment: @Red Lion: You can use a TreeMap or a HashMap, whichever you think better suits your needs.

Comment: A HashMap does not implement SortedMap so of those two you would want to use a TreeMap