# Java Map with keys of 3 columns

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I need a map in which my key should be based on 3 columns, say `C1, C2, C3`. `C1` has highest priority. `C2` has one less than `C1` and `C3` has one less than `C2`.

How do i create key in the map such that if somebody asks for information on `C1`, I should able to give all the values which has `C1`. I also should be able to return all the values if asked for `C1 & C2`

Comment: Can you show us some test cases?  What is your input and your output?

Comment: Question is not clear....

Comment: This is not a standard problem. Lets approach this problem specific to current scenario for your usage. Can you please tell what is the data type of C1,C2 and C3 ? If they are integers then what would be the range of them?

Comment: Can you share some sample values for C1, C2 and C3 in a tabular format with columns C1, C2 and C3 ?

Comment: I don't understand the question, but also see  [SortedMap with multiple fields for keys and values](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3452517), and  [How to implement a Map with multiple keys?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/822322),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same strategy as multicolumn indexes in databases, if your key columns can be ordered (i.e., in Java, they need to be `Comparable`) and can easily define maximum and minimum values for all but the first.

An example with integer columns:

```
public class Key implements Comparable<Key> {
    int c1, c2, c3;

    private static final int c2_min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    private static final int c2_max = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    private static final int c3_min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    private static final int c3_max = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Key o) {
        if (c1!=o.c1) return Integer.compare(c1, o.c1);
        if (c2!=o.c2) return Integer.compare(c2, o.c2);
        return Integer.compare(c3, o.c3);
    }

    // constructor, equals, ...

}
```

and then you can get all entries for some value `k1` in `c1` like this:

```
map.subMap(new Key(k1, Key.c2_min, 0), new Key(k1, Key.c2_max, 0));
```

Likewise, using the first two columns:

```
map.subMap(new Key(k1, k2, Key.c3_min), new Key(k1, k2, Key.c3_max));
```

Comment: Thanks, I have question my type is byte[]. How Do I define MAX and MIN Value

Comment: Assuming a [byte comparator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108091/java-comparator-for-byte-array-lexicographic), you can use `MIN = new byte[0]`. For `MAX`, if you have a maximum array size, just use it and initialize all elements with `Byte.MAX_VALUE`. Otherwise, you have to choose some instance (defined as `static final`) and explicitly check for it in `compareTo` with `==`. Finally, depending on your application, `null` might also work as a maximum value by considering it explicitly in `compareTo`.

Answer (score 2):

Use three maps.

```
One Map<C1, V> and one Map<C2, V> and one Map<C3, V>.
```

You can wrap the three maps into a class and implement you method.

Answer (score 0):

By "priority", I presume you mean what is usually referred to as primary, secondary and tertiary keys.

If they're all string fields, concatenate them into a single string and use that as the key. In your case, the key is C1+C2+C3 (where "+" refers to string concatenation).

Comment: but then how will you fetch values only corresponding to C1 or only C1 and C2?

Answer (score 0):

A Map will always return just one value for a key. You can't have it return multiple values based on your key classes content.

The simple way is to keep a separate map for each key type  and return the appropriate results based on the passed key.

Answer (score 0):

A three-level index where a higher-level key can be used to access all lower level keys and objects will require a three-level map.

```
class ThreeLevelMap<K1,K2,K3,V>
{
    private Map<K1,Map<K2,Map<K3,V>>> store = new HashMap<K,Map<K2,Map<K3,V>>>();
    ...
    public V put(K1 key1, K2 key2, K3 key3, V value) { ... }
    public V get(K1 key1, K2 key2, K3 key3) { ... }

    public static class TLMEntry<K1,K2,K3,V>
    {
    ...
    }
    public Collection<TLMEntry<K1,K2,K3,V>> get(K1 key1, K2 key2) { ... }
    public Collection<TLMEntry<K1,K2,K3,V>> get(K1 key1) { ... }
}
```

This is a basic skeleton but should get you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

This seems more like a database problem.  If you had a database with a table structured like:

```
CREATE TABLE MyMap (
    id IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    c1 int, -- Change data types as needed.
    c2 int,
    c3 int,
    v  int);
```

then you would simply issue SELECT statements against it. You might want to use any of the in-memory Java databases.

If you don't want to do that, you could do the equivalent purely in Java functionally by writing a container class value class:

```
class Cdata {
    private int c1;
    private int c2;
    private int c3;
    private int v;
    // Constructors and getters elided.
    public boolean match(int c1) {
        return this.c1 == c1;
    }
    public boolean match(int c1, int c2) {
        return match(c1) && this.c2 == c2;
    }
    public boolean match(int c1, int c2, int c3) {
        return match(c1, c2) && this.c3 == c3;
    }
}
```

Then create a List and use a functional programming library with filter methods.  Or, wait for Java 8 lambdas.  Using a `Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Integer>>>>` is too confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TreeMap to acheive your usecase. I am assuming the following:
Your three columns map to 3 increasing integer values i.e

> C1 = 1, C2 = 2, C3 =3

where C1 = 1 is the highest priority and C2 = 2 is next in line and so on.

Note: Your keys need not always be Integers, you can use any type if you provide the proper `Comparator` to your `TreeMap`.

With this in place, you could do something like:

```
TreeMap<Integer, String> treeMap = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
treeMap.put(1, "One");
treeMap.put(2, "two");
treeMap.put(3, "three");

List<String> list = getMappedValues(treeMap, 1);// returns One, Two, Three
//List<String> list = getMappedValues(treeMap, 2);// returns Two, Three
//List<String> list = getMappedValues(treeMap, 3);// returns Three
//List<String> list = getMappedValues(treeMap, 4);// returns null
if(list != null){
    //do something with the list of values
}

private static List<String> getMappedValues(TreeMap<Integer, String> map, Integer key) {
    Entry<Integer, String> e = map.ceilingEntry(key);
    if(e == null){
        return null;
    }
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(e != null){
        list.add(e.getValue());
        key = e.getKey();
        e = map.higherEntry(key);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> 

```
private class C {

    public C() {
        Map <Object ,String> ObjectC =new HashMap<Object, String>();
    }
}

private class B {

    public B() {
        Map <Object ,C> ObjectB =new HashMap<Object, C>();
    }
}

private class A {

    public A() {
        Map <Object ,B> ObjectA =new HashMap<Object, B>();
    }
}
```

So this could promise you a beautiful structure for which you don't need do more work further as 
You can get All the content of A

```
MapVar.ObjectA.get(C1);
```

if both C1, C2 are given You can call

```
MapVar.ObjectA.get(C1).ObjectB.get(C2);
```

if both C1, C2 , C3 are given You can call

```
MapVar.ObjectA.get(C1).ObjectB.get(C2).ObjectC.get(C3);;
```

Then you can simply iterate through the map and get values .

Answer (score 0):

Taking inspiration from how we would've handled this if we had access to a database.

Suppose, we have a table with columns as - C1, C2, C3, Value.

And given the requirement that following would be the query patterns:

1. select * from tbl where C1 = "input1";
2. select * from tbl where C1 = "input1" and C2 = "input2";
3. select * from tbl where C1 = "input1" and C2 = "input2" and C3 = "input3";

In such scenarios, it would be better if we use a multi-column index on (C1, C2, C3) in that particular order - which would internally create 3 separate indexes as:

- Index1 - C1  (Useful for queries of type 1.)
- Index2 - C1 and C2  (Useful for queries of type 2.)
- Index3 - C1 and C2 and C3 (Useful for queries of type 3.)

We can follow a similar strategy in Java - to define 3 maps:

- Map1 - Map<C1, Set>
- Map2 - Map<C1+C2, Set> (Here key is concatenation of string values of C1 and C2)
- Map3 - Map<C1+C2+C3, Set> (Here key is concatenation of string values of C1, C2 and C3)

So, based on the keys passed for fetch query, we pick the appropriate map.
For example:

- get(K1) - we will fetch from Map1
- get(K1, K2) - we will fetch from Map2
- get(K1, K2, K3) - we will fetch from Map3

Note that, this would require us to insert/delete in/from all the 3 maps for registering new data and deleting existing data